# How to Preselect value using Datalist Dropdown in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu, html-datalist, dynamic-data-list

I have an editable dropdown in which I need to autopopulate its default value from a template.
The default value is fetched from "this.Model.Application.environment" that has "dev" as a value. The below code gives me a editable dropdown but I need to preselect the value from the template. The [(ngModel)]="this.Model.Application.environment" in  is showing the default value("dev") on the page, but it does not show the other drop down values("qa/prod) and also its not editable. so I removed ngModel from  tag. Please help me how to crack it.
The requirement is
1.editable dropdown,
2.preselect the value,
3.show other values in the dropdown. (1 & 3 is working now)

```
<div class="select-editable">
   <input list="envVal" id="environment" name="environment" #select class="form-control"                              placeholder="Select Base Image Version" size="medium"                             style="width:326px; padding-top:5px;max-width: 100%;" (change)='updatebaseimageversion($event)' />
      <datalist id="envVal" [(ngModel)]="this.fmGeneratorModel.Application.environment">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let env of environmentList">
            <option [ngValue]="env" [selected]="env === 'dev'" >{{env}}</option>
         </ng-container>
      </datalist>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `[(ngModel)]` only with `input` elements. In your example it used with `datalist` - that's wrong.

Simple working example:

```
<label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
  <input list="browsers" name="browser" [(ngModel)]="model" #browser>
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Edge">
    <option value="Firefox">
   ...
  </datalist>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Tony Marko. I have given the [(ngModel)] in input element. but now the default values is getting set. but the dropdown is not working.

Comment: Do you have errors in console? Because it's should work. Simple working example on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ygemm2?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I am not getting any errors. I am getting only one output, either the default value when i use ngmodel or the dropdown values. Both i am not getting

Comment: Even if input is clean you have no options? Can you make example on stackblitz?

Comment: Hi @Tony, It was a testing mistake from my end. I was testing without removing the value in the textbox. Thank you for your support